# Usage of the verb ''Come Along''

Tags: word-usage

While in the act of searching for the synonym of **appear**, I stumbled upon a word, which is **come along**. In fact, I've two questions regarding the usage of this verb.

> It **comes along like** you won't earn anything from that game.

My goal was to say that

> It **seems/looks like** you won't earn anything from that game.

However, I don't know if that's grammatically correct or incorrect.

Regards!

Comment: unrelated, but you cannot contract "I have" when "have" is not an auxiliary verb. You can when it is an auxiliary verb, e.g."I've got two questions" or "I've been thinking".

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding **come along**. It means "to arrive on the scene", "to appear on the scene", "to show up".

> When Mr or Mrs Right comes along, you will know it.
>
> We need to finish this heist before the night watchman comes along.
>
> We've been waiting here for over an hour, but a bus hasn't come along.